# OutOfRangeError while training StyleGan2 network

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, stylegan

I've been running into plenty of problems training my first network using the [StyleGAN2](https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan2) repo and after changing to a smaller GPU batch size of 2 because of only 11GB of VRAM available to me the training manages to get through 1-4 ticks before returning these OutOfRangeErrors.

Ryzen 3950x
RTX 2080ti
32GB DDR4 RAM
Windows 10
Tensorflow-gpu 1.4

```
Building TensorFlow graph...
Initializing logs...
Training for 25000 kimg...

tick 0     kimg 10065.1  lod 0.00  minibatch 32   time 1m 17s       sec/tick 77.4    sec/kimg 605.07  maintenance 0.0    gpumem 8.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TE 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1356, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Users\TE 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1341, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\TE 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1429, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Out of range: End of sequence
     [[{{node GPU0/DataFetch/IteratorGetNext}}]]
     [[GPU0/DataFetch/UpscaleLOD/Cast/_5109]]
  (1) Out of range: End of sequence
     [[{{node GPU0/DataFetch/IteratorGetNext}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_training.py", line 202, in <module>
    main()
  File "run_training.py", line 197, in main
    run(**vars(args))
  File "run_training.py", line 128, in run
    dnnlib.submit_run(**kwargs)
  File "C:\ML\stylegan2dv\dnnlib\submission\submit.py", line 343, in submit_run
    return farm.submit(submit_config, host_run_dir)
  File "C:\ML\stylegan2dv\dnnlib\submission\internal\local.py", line 22, in submit
    return run_wrapper(submit_config)
  File "C:\ML\stylegan2dv\dnnlib\submission\submit.py", line 280, in run_wrapper
    run_func_obj(**submit_config.run_func_kwargs)
  File "C:\ML\stylegan2dv\training\training_loop.py", line 308, in training_loop
    tflib.run(data_fetch_op, feed_dict)
  File "C:\ML\stylegan2dv\dnnlib\tflib\tfutil.py", line 31, in run
    return tf.get_default_session().run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\TE 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 950, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\TE 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1173, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\TE 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1350, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\TE 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1370, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Out of range: End of sequence
     [[node GPU0/DataFetch/IteratorGetNext (defined at C:\ML\stylegan2dv\training\dataset.py:136) ]]
     [[GPU0/DataFetch/UpscaleLOD/Cast/_5109]]
  (1) Out of range: End of sequence
     [[node GPU0/DataFetch/IteratorGetNext (defined at C:\ML\stylegan2dv\training\dataset.py:136) ]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node GPU0/DataFetch/IteratorGetNext:
 Dataset/IteratorV2 (defined at C:\ML\stylegan2dv\training\dataset.py:119)

Input Source operations connected to node GPU0/DataFetch/IteratorGetNext:
 Dataset/IteratorV2 (defined at C:\ML\stylegan2dv\training\dataset.py:119)

Original stack trace for 'GPU0/DataFetch/IteratorGetNext':
  File "run_training.py", line 202, in <module>
    main()
  File "run_training.py", line 197, in main
    run(**vars(args))
  File "run_training.py", line 128, in run
    dnnlib.submit_run(**kwargs)
  File "C:\ML\stylegan2dv\dnnlib\submission\submit.py", line 343, in submit_run
    return farm.submit(submit_config, host_run_dir)
  File "C:\ML\stylegan2dv\dnnlib\submission\internal\local.py", line 22, in submit
    return run_wrapper(submit_config)
  File "C:\ML\stylegan2dv\dnnlib\submission\submit.py", line 280, in run_wrapper
    run_func_obj(**submit_config.run_func_kwargs)
  File "C:\ML\stylegan2dv\training\training_loop.py", line 208, in training_loop
    reals_write, labels_write = training_set.get_minibatch_tf()
  File "C:\ML\stylegan2dv\training\dataset.py", line 136, in get_minibatch_tf
    return self._tf_iterator.get_next()
  File "C:\Users\TE 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py", line 426, in get_next
    output_shapes=self._structure._flat_shapes, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\TE 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_dataset_ops.py", line 1974, in iterator_get_next
    output_shapes=output_shapes, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\TE 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 788, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\TE 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\TE 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3616, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\TE 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2005, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
```